# Rails 3: Given a player, find the number of times they have been paired with each opponent

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3.2. My schema is quite more complex but simplifying, I have Pcs (representing players), Games and Projects such that:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :projects

class Pc < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :projects

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :games
   belongs_to :pc
```

note: there's a table for GameProject as well for the many-to-many association.

I am trying to find a query (ActiveRecord is preferred over fully raw SQL) such that, given a Pc, returns the number of games each one of the other Pcs has played against them. A Pc has played against another one if there are project(s) of the two of them in the same game. An example situation would be:

```
+------+---------+----+
| Game | Project | Pc |
+------+---------+----+
|    1 |       1 |  1 |
|    1 |       2 |  1 |
|    1 |       3 |  1 |
|    1 |       4 |  2 |
|    1 |       5 |  2 |
|    2 |       6 |  1 |
|    2 |       7 |  2 |
|    3 |       8 |  1 |
|    3 |       9 |  3 |
+------+---------+----+
```

If I want to find out how many times each opponent has played against Pc1, the result should be:

```
{2 => 2, 3 => 1}
```

As Pc2 has played in two games with Pc1 and Pc3 has played only once with Pc1.
I don't care if Pc1 itself appears in the result, I'll just not process it afterwards.

The same query for Pc2 should return:

```
{1 => 2, 3 => 0}
```

As Pc1 has played twice with Pc1 and Pc3 has not played in any game with Pc2.

I've been trying for a while but I can't seem to get it right.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

I think I found a raw sql query that does the job (still have to test it). By looking at it, it doesn't look like it can be done using ActiveRecord query methods. The query is the following:

```
sql = "
SELECT 
  pc_id, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT(game_id)) 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
    g.id as game_id,  
    p.pc_id as pc_id 
  FROM games g
  INNER JOIN game_projects gp ON gp.game_id = g.id 
  INNER JOIN projects p ON p.id = gp.project_id
  WHERE g.id IN (SELECT g2.id FROM games g2 JOIN game_projects gp2 ON gp2.game_id = g2.id JOIN projects p2 ON p2.id = gp2.project_id AND p2.pc_id = #{pc.id}) 
  ) AS t 
GROUP BY pc_id;"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).to_a
```

**EDIT 2**

I seem to have found a solution by splitting the query and the subquery in two:

```
game_ids = Game.joins(:projects).where('projects.pc_id = ?', pc.id).map(&:id)
Pc.joins(:projects => :games).where('games.id IN (?)', game_ids).group('pcs.id').count
```

or even simplier, with the second one being:

```
Project.joins(:games).where('games.id IN (?)', game_ids).group('projects.pc_id').count
```

**EDIT 3**

> I don't care if Pc1 itself appears in the result, I'll just not process it afterwards.

To avoid this, we can add `AND projects.pc_id != ?` to the `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up splitting the query in two, which made it much simpler.

```
game_ids = Game.joins(:projects).where('projects.pc_id = ?', pc.id).map(&:id)
Project.joins(:games).where('games.id IN (?) AND projects.pc_id != ?', game_ids, pc.id).group('projects.pc_id').count
```